# jquery vertical ticker clone and clear

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a really short code for vertical ticker, so far this is my code and it's working fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var the_first = $('.vticker ul li:eq(0)');      
        var li1 = $('.vticker ul li:eq(0)').outerHeight();
        var li2 = $('.vticker ul li:eq(1)').outerHeight();
        var li3 = $('.vticker ul li:eq(2)').outerHeight();      
        var three = li1 + li2 + li3 ;

        $('.vticker').height(three);

        //Animate
        setInterval( function(){    
            var the_height = the_first.outerHeight();
            $('.vticker ul').animate({ marginTop: '-=' + the_height + 'px'}, 900, function(){
                the_first.clone().insertAfter('.vticker ul li:last');               
                the_first = the_first.next();               
            });
        }, 2000);

    });
</script>
```

The only problem is that if you'll look at the DOM with the inspect element, you will see that each 2 seconds I clone it and it creates a new li
 I would like to clear that li that isn't showing up.

HTML + CSS:

```
<style>
    .vticker { width:300px; overflow:hidden; background:#eee; border:8px solid #fff; box-shadow:0 0 4px #bbb; }
    .vticker ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    .vticker ul li { font-size:12px; border-bottom:1px dashed #bbb; list-style:none; font-family:'Arial'; padding:10px; }
    .vt_title { color:#f44837; font-weight: bold; padding:8px 0;  }
    .vt_content { color:#555555; }
    .vt_date { padding:4px 0; color:#555555; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; }
</style>

<div class="vticker">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="vt_title">City Room: New York Today: ‘The Wintry Mix Has Commenced’ </div>
                <div class="vt_content">indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately1.7 </div>
                <div class="vt_date">02/02/2015</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="vt_title">Australian Leader Pledges to Abandon Unpopular Policies </div>
                <div class="vt_content">In a speech, Prime Minister Tony Abbott, who has been in office less than two years, said he would refocus on the economy and consult more with his party colleagues.</div>
                <div class="vt_date">02/02/2015</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="vt_title">Latest News: New England Patriots, Katy Perry and Groundhog Day.</div>
                <div class="vt_content">indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately1.7 </div>
                <div class="vt_date">01/02/2015</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="vt_title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</div>
                <div class="vt_content">indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately1.7 </div>
                <div class="vt_date">01/02/2015</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post all code relevant to this question (html)?

Comment: Edited, Now you have it

Comment: ok, is your issue that you no longer want the `<li>` elements that are no longer shown on the page? (because currently, the longer this script is run, the more `<li>` elements will populate the dom)

Comment: Exactly, I want to prevent of cloning it to the DOM, or if you have a better solution to create this animation, I tried with only insertAfter, but i couldn't manage the animation

Comment: $('.vticker ul li:first').insertAfter( $('.vticker ul li:last') )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval( function(){
        $('ul li:first').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('ul li:first').insertAfter('ul li:last');
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I will try to add this the .effect(), I'll hope i could manage that